# Selected 'n' entries in nested list with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a nested list:

```
for i in my_lst:
    print(i)

output: 

['A', 2, 3]
['A', 3, 6]
['B', 11, 1]
['A', 13 3]
```

I am trying to only select lists where element 0 is 'A'... and only prints the first 2. I can do it but there must be an easier way.

```
count_max = 2
count = 0

for i, row in enumerate(my_lst):
    if row[0] == 'A':
        count+=1
        print(row)
        if count == count_max:
            break
```

`count_max = 2` is just an example. I want a generic way of select 'n' entries where the condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should just put that loop into a function and parse `count_max` as a parameter.

```
def select_lists(my_list, count_max=2):
    for i, row in enumerate(my_list):
        if row[0] == 'A':
            count += 1
            print(row)
            if count == count_max:
                break

select_lists(the_list, 5)
```

**EDIT**:
If you don't mind performance and want to you have less code this is less code using pythons in-list operations:

```
def select_lists(my_list, count_max=2):
    matches = [row for row in my_list if row[0] == 'A']
    print(matches[:count_max])
```

Comment: Ok. I was not sure if there was a simpler method to extract 'n' lists. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
count_max = 2
data = [['A', 2, 3],['A', 3, 6],['B', 11, 1],['A', 13, 3]]
for i,v in enumerate(data, 1):     #enumerate start index at 1
    if v[0] == "A":
        print(v)
    if i == count_max:             #Check if index equals count_max
        break
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 2, 3]
['A', 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind converting it to numpy array, you can do that :

```
n = 2
nestedList = np.array([['A', 2, 3], ['A', 3, 6], ['B', 11, 1], ['A', 13, 3]])
result = nestedList[(nestedList [:, 0] == "A"), :][:n].tolist()
```

Comment: Trying to avoid extension libraries, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension and slicing for a one-liner:

```
[a for a in my_lst if a[0]=='A'][:2]
```

Output:

```
[['A', 2, 3], ['A', 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also think about this problem as manipulating iterators.  There's already a function, `itertools.islice` for taking slices of iterators.

```
from itertools import islice

def take_n_where(it, n, condition):
    return islice(filter(condition, it), n)

def take_n_As(it, n):
    return take_n_where(it, n, lambda x: x[0] == 'A')

my_lst = [['A', 2, 3], ['A', 3, 6], ['B', 11, 1], ['A', 13, 3]]

for x in take_n_As(my_lst, 2):
    print(x)

# ['A', 2, 3]
# ['A', 3, 6]
```